# How to bind the BindingBase property to a variable in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm able to bind the property from entity to a listview content page element as below,

```
highlightGrid.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsPaymentPlanEnding");
```

But I want to how do I bind this "IsPaymentPlanEnding" property value to a variable. Trying with the below code, but it is throwing a compilation error.

```
bool IsPaymentPlanEnding = BindingContext.GetBindingValue("IsPaymentPlanEnding");
```

Please let me know how do I bind the entity property value to variable.

Comment: What's the compilation error being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your binding in a variable like this:

`BindingBase paymentPlanEndingBinding = new Binding("IsPaymentPlanEnding");`

Then reference it when doing the actual binding:

`highlightGrid.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, paymentPlanEndingBinding);`

I wrote a simple unit test for that:

```cs
[Test]
public void BindingBase_test()
{
    MockForms.Init();

    BindingBase binding = new Binding("Value");

    var pickerItem = new PickerSearchItem {Value = "the_value"};

    var label = new Label {BindingContext = pickerItem};
    label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, binding);
    
    label.Text.ShouldBe("the_value");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your BindingContext needs to Implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
And the BindingContext should hold a property (of type bool) called IsPaymentPlanEnding.
Then you can just leave the line as it is:
`highlightGrid.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, "IsPaymentPlanEnding");`

Learn about [Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/)

Comment: I don't think you answered the question here. The overload of Setbinding you mentioned here needs the path to the property (property name) as the second argument and that's what you provided - it is not the binding base.